# How do I use a gcloud auth print-access-token token with R bigrquery

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, credentials, bigrquery

I've logged into GCP from my terminal and browser.  I've run

```
gcloud auth print-access-token
```

And received a token in return.  With python I do the following:

```
t = 'my token'
p = 'my project'
credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(token=t)
client = bigquery.Client(project=p, credentials=credentials)
```

How do I use this with R and bigrquery?

"How to get your own API credentials" from get-api-credentials seems focused on getting some sort of permanent login solution sitting in a file.  That's not acceptable, I need a "I've just logged in and validated myself with GCP, now I want to do something" solution, that can be run from a Vertex AI notebook in the Cloud

Comment: Have you looked at this library [link](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery) and related [article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/google-cloud-platform-for-data-scientists-using-r-with-google-bigquery)?

Comment: Yes, and https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/how-gargle-gets-tokens.html
So far, all I've been able to find is code that demands that gargle be in charge of the authentication, and be given access to files holding client secret keys, etc.
That isn't going to happen
I've already got my authentication Oauth2 token, I just need some code willing to take it and use it, not go off and get its own token

Comment: Being paranoid is good, but in your example, I don't understand why. The [gargle](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql) package supports `bring your own token`, but you will need to write your own BigQuery code. AFAIK, nothing exists that meets your requirements. Maybe you can adapt `bigrquery` to meet your needs.

Comment: @JohnHanley where does gargle support that?  I tried this: foo <- credentials_byo_oauth2 (token = <token as string>)
Error in credentials_byo_oauth2(token = <token as string>) : 
  inherits(token, "Token2.0") is not TRUE
If there's any place that gargle will let me bring it a string token the way that https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html will, please point me to it, and I'll take care of the rest

Comment: GitHub has the source code. You can download the repo and modify anything you want. You do not show what `token as string` is. I also did not investigate what the package expects.

Comment: @JohnHanley I did not show what token as string is because it's the string token that gcloud auth print-access-token returned, and I don't want to let anyone else connect as me :-)

Comment: I meant the format of the token. There are ways to mask information to make it safe.

Comment: @JohnHanley ya29.a0AaA_aaAaAa0AA00aa00a0AAaaaAaa0AA00aaAaaa0A0a-aAA0AA0AAaaAA0AA_AAaAaaAAa0AaaAaAAA0A00aa_A0AAAAAAAa_aaAaaA0-0aAaAaA0AAaAA0aAAa00a0aaaaa0AAaaAAA0AAaA0AAaAaAaaa0aa0A0aaaAa00AaAaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA0Aa0a0Aa0AAAAaAAaAAAAAaAa0000
a means lower case, A means upper case, 0 means digit, left the rest alone
If there's a "format" there, I don't see it

Comment: That is not what I meant either. This will explain it in detail: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types#access-contents I cannot count the number of times someone said that they are using the token from `gcloud auth ...` but did not realize they saved an error or other message instead of a valid token. The document will show you how to verify tokens are valid and what they contain.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have currently lost all access, so I can't give useful answers.  Once I get access back, I may have a solution.  Thank you for the link, it was interesting